# Make active div for youtube URL a different shade

Tags: php, html, css, iframe

I have a page where in the top middle there is a large youtube player. Below it there are a bunch of youtube thumbnails which are clickable. Clicking them changes the player video to the thumbnail that was clicked. The youtube ID is passed thru the URL.

I wanted to change the shade of the thumbnail background so that the active ("clicked") thumbnail was shaded.

The following code generates the linked thumbnails:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $tubeID = $row['videoinfo'];
        echo
            '<div class="vid"><a href="videos.php?id=' . $tubeID . '"><img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/' . $tubeID . '/0.jpg" width="225" height="175"/></a></div>';
}
```

And the following code uses the clicked thumbnail to display the video:

```
<iframe id="player" width="640" height="385" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $_GET['id'] ?>" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

I know I need to compare the thumbnail URL to the current URL and if they match and set an ID to that thumbnail which can be assigned properties in CSS... though I'm not sure how to do so. Can someone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**edit** : this sorta explain what BZ suggested.

I kicked out some php to make the answer more concise. Don't forget to add it back.

```
<div class="vid">
  <a href="videos.php?id=$tubeID" id="m+$tubeID" onclick="changeVid(this);return false;">
    <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/01/0.jpg" width="225" height="175"/>
  </a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript>
  function changeVid(obj) {
    document.getElementById('player').src = "videos.php?id="+ substr(obj.id,1)
    document.getElementById(obj.id).style.visibility='visible'; //or other style
document.getElementById(obj.id).setAttribute("class", newClass); //For Most Browsers
    document.getElementById(obj.id).setAttribute("className", newClass); //For IE; harmless to other browsers.
  }
</script>
```

of course, I'd be a lot easier with a JS framework... (ie jquery)

Basically, when you click a link, the function is called, when it's done, `return false;` disable the page loading (ignoring the href).

The function will change the iframe source and then will add some custom styling to the link you clicked to load the new video.

*I've thrown a "m" in the link ID, because id can't start with numbers...*

edit : my function changeVid lack some reset function to remove the old thumbnail active state (easy way to solve it : remove the active state from all thumbnail then put the active state on the clicked thumbnail.)

Comment: Nice - much better example of it than mine was.  Thanks!

Comment: @Kraz But then I'd have to create separate stylings for every single youtube ID. I want the active thumbnail to be assigned an ID that is only assigned to one thumbnail at a time. That way I can get the active thumbnail to be a different shade.

Comment: @Kraz Additionally, when I use this code, none of my thumbnails display any more.

Comment: Re-read my first sentence : ___I kicked out some php___. It's why the thumbnail doesn't display anymore. The image link gotta be `<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/' . $tubeID . '/0.jpg" [...]`. Then, for the active thumbnail, just define a `.active` class, on page load, put in on the current video. When you click on a video, remove the class from all thumbnail and add it to the clicked one. Thay way, only the currently playing thumbnail will be shaded differently.

Comment: [Here's a __simplified__ version of what you could do](http://jsfiddle.net/FezCB/).

Answer (score 2):

In each link you could put an onclick attribute to do some javascript that would do the highlighting.

Comment: @BZ Can you elaborate on this? I'm still kinda new to this stuff